# tinymce messing with my font family and size

Tags: html, tinymce

I'm using tinymce in one of my websites and it works like a charm.. most of the time that is.

Sometimes when I put text in it tinymce is playing/messing with the font size and family changing it per textblock. It's very frustrating. How can I force tinymce to only use one font and font size?  Here is what it looks like in my DB:

This is only 2 different styles on 1 page but sometimes he does 3 or 4. I don't know where to start looking seeing it's so random.

```html
<p class="MsoNoSpacing" style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 7px 0px; font-size: 21px;"><span lang="NL" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"> Bacon ipsum dolor amet ham hock prosciutto boudin, turducken short loin bresaola drumstick hamburger picanha cupim tri-tip pork belly beef ribs pastrami filet mignon. Cupim ribeye beef ribs tri-tip picanha jerky brisket rump. Shoulder tail pork chop kielbasa cow flank bresaola landjaeger. Sausage tail shoulder pork chop jerky filet mignon shankle pastrami tri-tip brisket. Alcatra strip steak prosciutto, sirloin chicken short ribs andouille.
<span lang="NL" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 11pt; line-height: 15.6933px; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><br style="box-sizing: border-box;" />Buffalo pig pastrami venison, beef ribs shoulder meatball chicken turkey swine ground round flank. Bacon brisket cupim meatball tenderloin, swine rump meatloaf doner salami flank pig frankfurter tail jerky. Hamburger jerky pork belly strip steak filet mignon ham tongue fatback rump kevin shank tail shankle brisket sausage. Pork loin fatback porchetta frankfurter pork picanha short loin, leberkas ham flank tenderloin tail t-bone.
</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is formatted text from office/word (Mso = MicroSoftOffice). Rich text keeps its formatting between Office and TinyMCE, same between other rich text editors.

Use paste as plain text to prevent this or try a plugin like this: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/ or https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/powerpaste/

I tend to paste text in Notepad before pasting it in TineMCE.